# I can't add an img file to QGIS 2.8.1 on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: qgis

When I try to add an img file to QGIS 2.8.1 with Ubuntu 15.04 I get this error message:
Raster layer: /media/thomsec/D/Nu_Data/world/ocean_floor/age.3.2.img/age.3.2.img is not a supported raster data source

gdalinfo --format indicates that GDAL supports img files.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `gdalinfo --formats` indicates that GDAL supports **.img** files but they are the HFA Erdas Imagine Images. The Mercator projected **.img** files that you can download from here:

http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/ocean_age/data/2008/grids/age/

they can be accessed with Wessel and Smith's Generic Mapping Tools (GMT) program        **img2mercgrd** (see [readme.txt](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/ocean_age/data/2008/grids/age/readme.txt) file):

```
img2mercgrd age3.2.img -R<west>/<east>/<south>/<north> -Gage3.2_myregion.grd -T1 -S0.01 -D-80.738/80.738
```

For this reason could be preferable to download the [age.3.2.zip](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/ocean_age/data/2008/grids/age/age.3.2.zip) file; where it is a short integer GeoTiff formatted file (and its corresponding tfw file). The age units in the **.tif** file are in millions of years (multiplied by 100) and the geographic grid spans longitudes from 0 E to 360 E and latitudes from 90 N to -90 N (see [readme.txt](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/ocean_age/data/2008/grids/age/readme.txt) file).

Comment: If it was useful you can mark it as accepted. Thanks.